# The netgear r8000's three "separate" bands?

Tags: wireless-router

Does netgear's r8000 router's 3 separate bands use 3 separate ssid's, or do the two 5ghz bands work as one?

Also if it was used as a repeater, is it possible to use the 3 different bands totally separate for each other? Like if you had a 2.4GHz band and two 5GHz bands from different routers could you repeat those all with seperate ssid's from this one router? Assuming there all on the same network of course.

This 3 band concept is new to me but was looking into a new router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this really amounts to is that the device has three radios, one 2.4GHz and two 5GHz.  The 5GHz radios will operate on two different channels.

So, to answer your first question, if you enable the "Smart Connect" feature, the two do work as one, balancing the devices/traffic between the two to help prevent congestion.  If you want to run the two 5GHz radios with different configurations, you would need to disable "Smart Connect".

Not sure what you mean by using it as a repeater, as a repeater simply repeats a signal on the same channel as itself. If your primary wireless device only operates one 5GHz radio, then the second one won't do you any good as a repeater.

Comment: What I meant is if you happened to have two 5ghz bands and one 2.4ghz band from different routers, could this router reapeat 3 bands seperately? We probably have an "over-complicated" wireless network here at work so the 3 bands seemed intriguing to me with the right flexibility.